# WP7 SQL Server CE insertion order

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

While writing app I assumed that the order in which items are added into the table will be the order in which they are got by query.

Today after small refactor I see that sorting is a bit broken. Items are ordered a bit differently.

For example if I have entities with names equal `1,2,3,4,5,6` in db they will be saved like `1,2,4,3,5,6`. Something like that.

Any ideas why could this happen? Definitely such kind of assumptions is bad, but it worked and saved much time.

Comment: Are you saying .OrderBy isn't working?

Comment: OrderBy works. But i wish i could get data without it, coz i inserted it in sorted order.

Comment: You cannot expect ordering of relational data without ORDER BY